# Resolving .lxc container names on the host

Tags: 16.04, lxc, dnsmasq

I am using LXC (version 2.1.3) as shipped with Ubuntu 16.04, and have followed the recommendations for setup (`lxd init`).

There are lots of tutorials around that explain how to have a container's IP address started with `lxc start mycontainer` to be locally resolved from `mycontainer.lxc`. These instructions involve dnsmasq and work fine with Ubuntu 14.04.

With 16.04 there seem to be many changes, so I am unable to for example get the container's IP address with `nslookup mycontainer.lxc` or `dig @10.0.3.1 mycontainer.lxc`.

Any help would be highly appreciated. If later versions of LXD/LXC solve this problem, I'm also happy to install those.